# Pandapipes problem- PipeflowNotConverged problem

Tags: python

```
I am trying to calculate supply and return temperature from a heat model. It is a district heating model.
```

this is my whole code

#simple version of 1508105

```
!pip install pandapipes==0.8.4!pip install --upgrade pandapipesimport pandapipes as ppfrom pandapipes.component_models import Pipe
```

```
create empty net
```

```
net = pp.create_empty_network(fluid ="water")
```

```
create fluid
```

```
pp.create_fluid_from_lib(net, "water", overwrite=True)
```

```
create junctions
```

```
junction1 = pp.create_junction(net, pn_bar=3, tfluid_k=293.5, name="Junction A")junction2 = pp.create_junction(net, pn_bar=3, tfluid_k=293.5, name="junction B")junction3 = pp.create_junction(net, pn_bar=3, tfluid_k=293.5, name="Junction C")junction4 = pp.create_junction(net, pn_bar=3, tfluid_k=293.5, name="Junction 0")junction5 = pp.create_junction(net, pn_bar=3, tfluid_k=293.5, name="Junction 1")junction6 = pp.create_junction(net, pn_bar=3, tfluid_k=293.5, name="Junction 1a")junction7 = pp.create_junction(net, pn_bar=3, tfluid_k=293.5, name="Junction 1b")junction8 = pp.create_junction(net, pn_bar=3, tfluid_k=293.5, name="Junction 1c")junction9 = pp.create_junction(net, pn_bar=3, tfluid_k=293.5, name="Junction 1d")
```

```
#external grid#pp.create_ext_grid(net, junction=junction1, p_bar=6, t_k=343.15, name="External Grid", type="pt")
```

```
#pipepp.create_pipe_from_parameters(net, from_junction=junction1, to_junction=junction4, length_km=.2,diameter_m=0.0545, k_mm=1,alpha_w_per_m2k=.3,text_k=283.15,name="Pipe 1")pp.create_pipe_from_parameters(net, from_junction=junction2, to_junction=junction4, length_km=.1,diameter_m=0.026, k_mm=1,alpha_w_per_m2k=.2,text_k=283.15, name="Pipe 2")pp.create_pipe_from_parameters(net, from_junction=junction3, to_junction=junction4, length_km=.2,diameter_m=0.0372, k_mm=1,alpha_w_per_m2k=.25,text_k=283.15, name="Pipe 3")pp.create_pipe_from_parameters(net, from_junction=junction4, to_junction=junction5, length_km=0.1,diameter_m=0.0545,k_mm=1,alpha_w_per_m2k=.3,text_k=283.15,name="Pipe 4")pp.create_pipe_from_parameters(net, from_junction=junction5, to_junction=junction6, length_km=.025,diameter_m=0.026, k_mm=1,alpha_w_per_m2k=.2,text_k=283.15, name="Pipe 5")pp.create_pipe_from_parameters(net, from_junction=junction6, to_junction=junction7, length_km=.050,diameter_m=0.021, k_mm=1,alpha_w_per_m2k=.15,text_k=283.15, name="Pipe 6")pp.create_pipe_from_parameters(net, from_junction=junction5, to_junction=junction8, length_km=0.025,diameter_m=0.026, k_mm=1, alpha_w_per_m2k=.2,text_k=283.15,name="Pipe 7")pp.create_pipe_from_parameters(net, from_junction=junction8, to_junction=junction9, length_km=.050,diameter_m=0.021, k_mm=1,alpha_w_per_m2k=.15,text_k=283.15, name="Pipe 8")
```

```
#Heat-pump (HP)
```

```
P1 = pp.create_pump(net, from_junction=junction2, to_junction=junction4, std_type="P1")
```

```
#heatExchangerpp.create_heat_exchanger(net, from_junction=junction5, to_junction=junction6, diameter_m=.026, qext_w = 100000)pp.create_heat_exchanger(net, from_junction=junction6, to_junction=junction7, diameter_m=.021, qext_w = 100000)pp.create_heat_exchanger(net, from_junction=junction5, to_junction=junction8, diameter_m=.026, qext_w = 100000)pp.create_heat_exchanger(net, from_junction=junction8, to_junction=junction9, diameter_m=.021, qext_w = 100000)
```

```
#sourcesourceA = pp.create_source(net, junction=junction1,mdot_kg_per_s=0.234,  patch_type="circle", size=0.1, color="green", zorder=200)sourceB = pp.create_source(net, junction=junction3, mdot_kg_per_s=0.234, patch_type="circle", size=0.1, color="green", zorder=200)
```

```
pp.pipeflow(net)
```

this is my error:

```
PipeflowNotConverged                      Traceback (most recent call last)
\<ipython-input-5-cd1256d900dc\> in \<cell line: 62\>()
60 sourceB = pp.create_source(net, junction=junction3, mdot_kg_per_s=0.234, patch_type="circle", size=0.1, color="green", zorder=200)
61
\---\> 62 pp.pipeflow(net)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandapipes/pipeflow.py in pipeflow(net, sol_vec, \*\*kwargs)
99         converged, \_ = hydraulics(net)
100         if not converged:
\--\> 101             raise PipeflowNotConverged("The hydraulic calculation did not converge to a solution.")
102
103     if calculate_heat:

PipeflowNotConverged: The hydraulic calculation did not converge to a solution.
```

How can i fix this issue? Please give me some idea.
I am expecting supply and temperatures from each junction.